# Android - Buttons added programatically fall off the screen

Tags: android

I have added buttons programatically on screen but some of the buttons fall of the screen. How can I do that all buttons will show on the screen. I have the following code on adding the buttons programatically.

```
for (String string : str_array) {
            counter++;
            final int value = counter;
            LinearLayout l_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout); 
            l_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(string);
            btn.setId(counter);
            l_layout.addView(btn);

        }
```

Then I have this code in my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add layout_width and layout_height params to buttons programmatically.

Comment: I added these: LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.La‌​youtParams.WRAP_CONTENT); btn.setLayoutParams(lp); but still buttons fall-off the screen @vjdhama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is horizontal so it could you have many buttons added, and unable to fit the device width. You have to use `HorizontalScrollView` as parent to the `LinearLayout` in your layout xml

Change you layout as

```
<HorizontalScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot on what you see now?

Comment: sorry I cannot post an image since I am new to StackOverflow. my reputation is very low. :) When I created the button dynamically, it should show in the screen that I have 6 buttons, but I can only view 4 buttons on the screen. When I changed the textSize of the buttons to 5, I can see the six buttons. but when I setTextSize to normal size, I can only see 4 buttons. :) please help me.

Comment: As i said , problem is its not able to fit all your button due to the device size. Are you able to scroll horizontally and see the other buttons?

Comment: still no buttons even if scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
for (String string : str_array) {
            counter++;
            final int value = counter;
            LinearLayout l_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout); 
            l_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            Button btn = new Button(this);

   LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
  btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            btn.setText(string);
            btn.setId(counter);
            l_layout.addView(btn);

        }
```

Comment: is there really a 1f argument in the LayoutParams? it reports an error. thanks

Comment: Of course yes 
you should import Layoutparams of linearlayout which i mention below
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

I hope it will solve your problem